# How to dynamically branch to multiple topics in kafka streams api using cloud stream binder?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

My streams api application reads a topic and sends it to multiple different topics depending on value received from field in input topic.

My code works well in Java, but now I have to build my application in spring boot and dynamically configure a list of possible output topics in my yaml file and branch only off of those possible values. The list is created on application build (fetched from the outside). All other fields which are not provided in that list will not be included in the branching and will be skipped.

How do I go about reading possible output topics and integrating it with apache kafka cloud streams binder?

Is there a way to dynamically set output topics in this interface?

```
 interface KStreamProcessorWithBranches {

            @Input("input")
            KStream<?, ?> input();

            @Output("output1")
            KStream<?, ?> output1();

            @Output("output2")
            KStream<?, ?> output2();

            @Output("output3")
            KStream<?, ?> output3();
        }
```

Also maybe it's possible to integrate with configuration below somehow?

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            brokers: localhost:29092
      bindings:
         input_1:
           destination: mytopic1
           group: readgroup
         output_1:
           destination: mytopic2
         output_2:
           destination: mytopic4
         output_3:
           destination: mytopic6
.
.
.
```

Comment: Have you seen that example ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current-snapshot/reference/html/_apache_kafka_streams_binder.html#_multiple_output_bindings_aka_branching

Comment: Yes, but what's the best way to define output topics dynamically? Can I put a generated list in @SendTo() annotation and run @Output() annotation in a for loop?

Comment: Also can I get away without defining output topics in properties?